# Sitecore PowerShell : Remove-Item not deleting, How to troubleshoot?

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore8

I have simple Sitecore8/PowerShell script where I delete image child item  and publish parent item:

```
$child1 = Get-Item $child1Path
Remove-Item $child1 -Force -Permanently 
Publish-Item -Item $parent1 -Recurse -PublishMode SingleItem -Language "en*"
```

No deletion and no errors while running.

How can I find out why it's not deleting ?

Comment: the MSDocs site & my ps5.1 help files do NOT list a `-Permanently` parameter for `Remove-Item`. is that a customized wrapper or a version that comes with an added module?

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. This is sitecore powershell, and Remove-Item is for removing sitecore elements.it has the same name that Remove-Item for removing files or folders.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! [*grin*] i am out of my depth now, so i will go back to lurking ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Remove-Item with the -Path parameter. Or use

> $child1 | Remove-Item

Apparently you script don't throw an error but the remove is not working that way.
See the documentation https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items